# Purpose of `Mutex#synchronize` used with `ConditionVariable#signal`

Tags: ruby

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636746) by railscard and the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/ConditionVariable.html) for `ConditionVariable` suggest code similar to the following:

```
m = Mutex.new
cv = ConditionVariable.new 

Thread.new do
  sleep(3)  # A
  m.synchronize{cv.signal}
end

m.synchronize{cv.wait(m)}
puts "Resource released."  # B
```

This code makes the process commented as `B` wait until `A` finishes.

I understand the purpose of `m.synchronize{...}` around `cv.wait(m)`. What is the purpose of `m.synchronize{...}` around `cv.signal`? How would it be different if I had the following instead?

```
m = Mutex.new
cv = ConditionVariable.new 

Thread.new do
  sleep(3)
  cv.signal
end

m.synchronize{cv.wait(m)}
puts "Resource released."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `cv` in `cv.wait(m)` to be unlocked, the `cv.signal` has to be emitted after `cv.wait`. In this particular case, that timing is most likely guaranteed because of `sleep(3)`, but otherwise, there is a danger of `cv.signal` being emitted before `cv.wait(m)`. If that happens, there will not be any `signal` to be emitted after `cv.wait(m)`, and the locked condition of `cv` will continue forever. The purpose of `m.synchronize{...}` around `cv.signal` is to ensure that it happens after `cv.wait(m)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's useless in this example, but it's required when you have any conditions or calculations before signaling to avoid race conditions.